# On the sum: $\sum_{i = 0}^n i {n \choose i} = n 2^{n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I need to prove that:
$$ \sum_{i = 0}^n ~ i ~ {n \choose i} = n ~ 2^{n-1} $$

Been stuck for a while now, will appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Try induction !